# Copy Gmail email in specific “label” to another Gmail account

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have a Gmail account with some email in a label called "oldMailers".

I want to copy that entire label and the mail in it to another Gmail account that I have.

Please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't "share" email between Gmail accounts (see:  https://support.google.com/a/answer/33330?hl=en ), one approach to accomplish what you need is to setup POP or SMTP access with the legacy account.

1. Enable POP (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en)

OPTION A- copy mail via a mail client such as Outlook

2. Setup your mail client to access both Gmail accounts.  If using MS Outlook or Mozilla Thunderbird [https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/], you should see to sets of "inboxes" and subfolders- one per account.
3. Once you've downloaded the full version of each message in the legacy account's "oldMailers" folder, you can drag & drop/copy to the desired folder in the new Gmail account.

---

OPTION B- copy mail via Gmail account (this theoretically should work, but you may risk confusion from having multiple labels with the same name in both accounts)

2. Then sign into your new Gmail account, and configure the legacy account from the IMPORT MAIL AND CONTACTS link in the Accounts & Import section of the "Settings" tab.
   [image: Gmail Settings > Accounts & Import]
3. Once you've configured POP access/import of the legacy Gmail account, you should see the "oldMailers" label/folder and can select all, apply a label/file away in a folder unique to your new Gmail account.